# Printing vector <string> to matrix

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++. I'm trying to implement a method which has to print a vector to a matrix, but my implementation works pretty dumb.
Here is an exampe how it should work: I have a vector which has 4 strings

```
std::vector<std::string> vec = {"abcd", "def", "ghi", "jkld"};
```

and the output should be a matrix where elements are right justified and have only 2 columns. The columns shold have equal width and the width is equal to the longest string + 1. Like this:

```
-------------
| abcd|  def|
|  ghi| jkld|
-------------
```

Here is what I've got:

```
void print_table(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<std::string>& vec){
        for (const auto& array : vec)
            out.width(); out << "-" << std::endl;

        for (auto x : vec) {
               out.width(); out<<"|" << std::right  << x<< " |";
               out.width(); out <<"|" << std::right  << x<< " | ";
        }
        out.width(); out << "-" << '\n';
}
```

I don't really understand what I'am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you read how the things you used are supposed to work? It looks like you don't understand what you are doing at all. Or else... what do you not understand precisely? What is happening? Currently you are saying "Here is the task, my code doesn't work".

Comment: @luk32 Yes, I don't really understand what I'm doing.

Comment: This should be fairly straightforward if you know the length of the longest string before you print anything.

Comment: @Lemmy Figure it out bit by bit. You need to split your task into more atomic elements. And ask precisely about things you don't get. E.g. your `width` does nothing. Not sure if you know why... You must have gotten some output. Here's a good start to read how things work: http://en.cppreference.com/

Comment: @Logicrat so I should use `sizeof`?

Comment: @Lemmy No, use `x.size()`. That will tell you the length of string `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested. Also caters for any length of vector, including odd lengths.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostream& print_tab(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::string>& vs)
{
    auto colwidth = std::max_element(std::begin(vs),
                                     std::end(vs),
                                     [](const auto& s1, const auto&s2)
                                     {return s1.length() < s2.length(); })->length();

    auto table_width = (colwidth + 1) * 2 + 3;

    os << std::string(table_width, '-');
    auto i = std::begin(vs);
    while (i != std::end(vs) )
    {
        os << std::endl << "|" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(colwidth + 1) << std::right << *i++;
        os << "|";
        if (i != std::end(vs)) {
            os << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(colwidth + 1) << std::right << *i++;
        }
        else {
            os << std::string(colwidth + 1, ' ');
        }
        os << '|';
    }
    os << std::endl << std::string(table_width, '-');


    return os;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto tab = vector<string> { "abcd", "def", "ghi", "jkld" };
    print_tab(cout, tab) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
-------------
| abcd|  def|
|  ghi| jkld|
-------------
```

Comment: Thank you! This one helped.